# Blank left and right delimiters produce an unknown symbol

Tags: fonts, environments, unicode-math, delimiters

I recently compiled one of my files after updating my TeX distribution (including the `unicode-math` package, as I use the MinionMath font set) and noticed a strange error. In my file I used a cases environment, and for some reason an unknown symbol was printed at the end of the environment. Here is a minimal example. When I input

```
\begin{equation*}
        f(x) \colonequals
         \begin{cases}
            1, & x ≤ 1  \\
            x, & x ≥ 1
        \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

it produces the following:

[image]

The same problem occurs when using the `\left.` and `\right.` blank delimiters, so I think that it's ultimately a problem with the delimiters. I was wondering if there's a way to make this unknown symbol go away.

I'm using the TeXLive distribution and compiling with XeLaTeX. Here's how I've loaded the fonts (which hasn't been a problem in the past 6 months).

```
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle}, Ligatures={Common}, ItalicFont={Minion Pro Italic}, BoldFont={Minion Pro Semibold}, BoldItalicFont={Minion Pro Semibold Italic}]{Minion Pro}
\setmonofont{Exemplar Pro}
\setmathfont[
    Extension = .otf,
    Scale = 1,
    Script = Math,
    SizeFeatures = {
        {Size = -6, Font = MinionMath-Tiny,
            Style = MathScriptScript},
        {Size = 6-8.4, Font = MinionMath-Capt,
            Style = MathScript},
        {Size = 8.4-13, Font = MinionMath-Regular,
            Style = MathScript},
        {Size = 13-19.9, Font = MinionMath-Subh,
            Style = MathScript},
        {Size = 19.9-72, Font = MinionMath-Disp},
        {Size = 72-, Font = MinionMath-Disp,
            Style = MathScript},
            },
        ]{MinionMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[range={\mathfrak}]{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal}]{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={\mathit}]{MinionMath-Regular.otf}
```

I'm using the `amsart` documentclass.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please state which TeX distribution and which LateX format (pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, something else?) you use. Also, how are the text and math fonts loaded?

Comment: Minion Math is a commercial font and not available for the public and package `unicode-minionmath` is not on CTAN and, of course, provide a _complete_ example which shows the behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I just took that line off; just a copy/paste error. In any case that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example with up-to-date TeXLive works well:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{colonequals}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont{MinionMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[range={\mathfrak,\mathcal}]{XITS Math}    
\begin{document}

foo \textit{bar} \textbf{baz}

\begin{equation*}
    f(x) \colonequals
    \begin{cases}
    1, & x ≤ 1  \\
    x, & x ≥ 1
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange...In previous versions I needed to have the line `\setmathfont[range={\mathit}]{MinionMath-Regular.otf}` at the end to get the spacing to work correctly, but removing it removed the error.